# I'm sorry I don't understand

Tags: word-choice

I have a series of useful phrases from [Jukuu](http://www.jukuu.com), that assist learners in developing conversations and learning new word/phrases. Which of these would be more appropriate for talking to a stranger?  Would I choose a different phrase for a doctor or for a family member? If other phrases are more appropriate please let me know.

謝謝！

```
Will you speak a little more slowly?
请你说得再慢一点，好吗?

I am sorry, sir. Can you repeat that more slowly, please?
对不起，请你再说慢点。

I'm sorry, can you repeat that.
对不起，您能重复一下吗？

A: Can you repeat that, please?
甲：请您再说一遍好吗?

Sorry, I don't understand.
对不起，我没明白。
```

### EDIT: To clarify this question. Please note that I am looking for the situation where one would use one phrase rather than another.

Examples might be:

Use phrase x when talking to family members (etc.)

Comment: Well, I think the translation are quite close to their literal meaning, so use them depend on the situation. The first 4 generally express your interest in continuing the conversation, but the last one may not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both five sentences above will be used under talking with strangers rather than people who you actually know. These are very polite expression and are in most case inter-changeable. However, it will be odd to talk to someone who you have already known with that level of politeness. It might work for Professor(s) / leader(s). Talking with friends or family will use more colloquial expression like

"稍微慢一点" "等一下，你说得太快了"

Comment: When talking to somebody very close, you could even just say "Huh!?" or 你很趕嗎！？(Are you in a rush!?)